# Difference between array(list()) and list() in R

Tags: r

can someone please tell me what is the difference in R between doing:

```
foo <- array(list())
```

and

```
foo <- list()
```

I have this doubt because I feel like I can use both of them in the same way, so I am curious to know if any difference exists.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

From `?array`

> An array in R can have one, two or more dimensions.  It is simply
>        a vector which is stored with additional attributes giving the
>        dimensions (attribute ‘"dim"’) and optionally names for those
>        dimensions (attribute ‘"dimnames"’).

Indeed you can check:

```
foo <- array(list())
str(foo);
# list()
# - attr(*, "dim")= int 0
is.list(foo);
# [1] TRUE
is.array(foo);
# [1] TRUE


foo <- list()
str(foo);
# list()
is.list(foo);
# [1] TRUE
is.array(foo);
# [1] FALSE
```

So `array(list())` is a `list` with an additional `dim` attribute.

---

In response to @clemens, let's take a different example:

```
foo <- array(list(a = 1));
str(foo);
#List of 1
# $ : num 1
# - attr(*, "dim")= int 1
```

Indexing works in the same way as with a `list`:

```
foo[[1]];
#[1] 1
```

And indeed

```
is.list(foo);
#[1] TRUE
```

---

An addition to @LenGreski's answer:

While `array`s are *homogeneous* structures, they can contain `list` elements, each of which can contain multiple types (as they are *inhomogeneous* structures).

For example,

```
foo <- array(list(a = 1, b = diag(3)));
sapply(foo, class)
#[1] "numeric" "matrix"
is.array(foo);
#[1] TRUE
is.list(foo);
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: the class of `array(list())` is still `"array"` though and `foo[[1]]` would return an error.

Comment: that's true. but `class(foo)` would still be `"array"` and `inherits(foo, "list")` is `FALSE`.  which of course does not make your answer incorrect. it is merely a side note.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Hadley Wickham in *Advanced R:*

> R's base data structures can be organized by their dimensionality (1d, 2d, 3d, etc.) and whether they are homogeneous (all contents of same type) or heterogeneous (contents of multiple types). This gives rise to the five most common types used in data analysis.

```
    Homogeneous      Heterogeneous
----------------------------------
1d  Atomic Vector    List
2d  Matrix           Data Frame
nd  Array
```

Using this framework, the key differences between an array and a data frame are:

1. Arrays are used when all elements are of the same type
2. Arrays can have more than 2 dimensions
3. A Matrix is the equivalent of a 2 dimensional array

### Reference

Wickham. H, *Advanced R*, page 13.